# Winforms MonthCalendar DateSelected event doesn't fire on first click of MaxDate

Tags: winforms, monthcalendar

As the title says, if I put a MonthCalendar on a form and set its MaxDate, then the first click on the max date does not fire the DateSelected event (though DateChanged will fire twice). It will fire on the first click on any other date, or on the *second* click on max date.

Is this a known bug? If so, is there a fix? Otherwise, any suggestions on a reasonable workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem and i found out, that DateChanged is triggert twice if clicked on max date.

The bug can be corrected if you set the MaxDate property of the control to the day AND with the timestamp of 23:59:59.

This worked for me and now it triggers 1 time DateChanged and afterwards 1 time DateSelected.

**Example without timestamp where 16.06.2015 is my MaxDate:**

```
DateChanged Start: 04.06.2015 End: 04.06.2015 23:59:59
DateSelected Start: 04.06.2015 End: 04.06.2015 23:59:59

DateChanged Start: 09.06.2015 End: 09.06.2015 23:59:59
DateSelected Start: 09.06.2015 End: 09.06.2015 23:59:59

DateChanged Start: 16.06.2015 End: 16.06.2015
DateChanged Start: 16.06.2015 End: 16.06.2015
```

**Example with timestamp where 16.06.2015 23:59:59 is my MaxDate:**

```
DateChanged Start: 10.06.2015 End: 10.06.2015 23:59:59
DateSelected Start: 10.06.2015 End: 10.06.2015 23:59:59

DateChanged Start: 15.06.2015 End: 15.06.2015 23:59:59
DateSelected Start: 15.06.2015 End: 15.06.2015 23:59:59

DateChanged Start: 16.06.2015 End: 16.06.2015 23:59:59
DateSelected Start: 16.06.2015 End: 16.06.2015 23:59:59
```